# input type number control - showing number value correct to 2 decimal place

Tags: angularjs, html

I am using  a form in a page AngularJs application.Below is sample code:

```
<form id="saveDailyCalFrm" name="saveDailyCalFrm" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <span> Name :</span>
      </div>
        <div class="hoursSize">
         <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" ng-model="name"  id="name"/>
    </div>

   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <span> Hours :</span>
      </div>
        <div class="hoursSize">
         <input class="form-control" name="hrs" type="number" ng-model="dailyHour"  id="dailyHours"/>
    </div>  

 </form>
```

Now If user click on a record in dashboard, I am showing the record in
    the form so that user can update it.

I need to show hour correct to 2 decimal place when a record is loaded in the form. For example as below :

```
    if hour = 4 then show 4.00
    if 2.5  then show 2.50 etc
```

I have written the code in controller.js (timeEntry is the model in which the record is stored):

```
$scope.dailyHour = (parseFloat($scope.timeEntry.HRS).toFixed(2));
```

But I am getting the below error:

> [ngModel:numfmt] Expected `3.50` to be a number

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string, not a number.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: Thanks for the comment.But I have also tried parseFloat(parseFloat($scope.timeEntry.HRS).toFixed(2)) i.e again converting the string to float even then it is not working

Answer (score 0):

> You Can try using this code i am sure you can done it.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {      
  $scope.value = 2.55;
});


app.directive('floatValue', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers = [];
      ngModel.$formatters = [];
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>

    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">   
    <p>      
      <input type="number" ng-model="value" float-value  />{{value}}
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have  tried you solution.I have tried        $scope.value = parseFloat(2.50).toFixed(2);(as have to show the value exact to 2 decimal place).But still i am getting same error

Comment: Can you please suggest any other solution?

Comment: Can you show me your code in plunker ? So, I'll solve better .

Comment: Yes  @Vijay you can refer below plunckr url in which I am trying to show hours up to 2 decimal place but it is not working:
http://plnkr.co/edit/IbxWSfxGc46dwYC7cRvR?p=preview